# visualforce rerender the parent page table from child

Tags: parent, visualforce, rerender

I want to refresh the part of (not whole page) the parent window by clicking the button on child window.

It it is like action="action name" rerender="id" on just one page.

But from child window, is it possible to rerender the parent page part(on my case it is table)?

Please, help.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is very unclear. It might help if you used a translation application to help communicate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Simply:

```
rerender="ioOfParentComponent"
```

This only pertains to the same page, however. If you're talking about IFrames then this will not work. But within the same `<apex:page > </apex:page>` block, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh a parent window from the child, and the child is a popup and both pages are custom visualforce pages - do it per javascript callback:

Parent window:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="callBackFunction" reRender="refreshMe" action=""/>

<apex:outputPanel id="refreshMe">
    Some text here...
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Child window (popup):

```
<apex:commandButton onClick="javascript:parent.window.opener.callBackFunction(); return false;" value="Refresh parent" />
```